# Using TabLayout and ViewPager in fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

I'm using `Tablayout` in fragment, and there is no problem.

[image]

but when i click on items and open details fragment (i add the new fragment in back stack) after pop back stack, The `Tablayout` root fragment just show tabs and viewPager is empty.

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: can you please elaborate more? Or post the snippet?

Comment: i updated my question with attach images @DeepPatel

Comment: try to use notifyDataSetChanged() for the adapter, after you do - pop back stack.

Comment: thank you. i did it ,but don't work, there is no change in adapter @IgorFridman

Comment: are you using onBackpressed method @ Behnam ?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here, it may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38568013/5223744

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved problem. should use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead `getSupportFragmentManager()` to assign view pager adapter