# Can't call notifydatasetchanged

Tags: android, arraylist, onactivityresult

I have an activity that's runs an startactivityforresult and a onactivityresult.  in the onactivityresult I can set the returned data to a variable and then put to add those variables to my arraylist, what I can't seem to do is use myAdapter.notifydatasetchanged() after this, just get a cannot resolve symbol. Is it because I created and declared the array in oncreate and the onactivityresult is not in oncreate?

Code snippets below...

Below done in oncreate

```
/*create array adapter and set to listview*/
    final ArrayAdapter<String> myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ListView_Activity.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.row_item_text_view, mylistarray);
    final ListView mylistview = findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
    mylistview.setAdapter(myadapter);
    mylistarray.add("Test");
    myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    final FloatingActionButton additembutton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    additembutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent additem = new Intent(ListView_Activity.this, Create_Item_Activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(additem, 1);
        }
    });
```

Then data retrieved here outside of oncreate;

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == ADD_NEW_ITEM){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                tempdescr = data.getStringExtra("tempdescr");
                tempname = data.getStringExtra("tempname");
                mylistarray.add(tempdescr);
                mylistarray.add(tempname);
                myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast replacewithcode = Toast.makeText(ListView_Activity.this, "replace with code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                replacewithcode.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code you're asking your question about?

Comment: notifydatasetchanged() is a method on adapter. What is myarray?

Comment: just added a bit of the code, was a little too quick typing forgot to paste it in my bad

Answer (score 1):

You're losing the array reference. Create the array as a global variable and add elements directly.
Check this out: [ArrayAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged() is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022727/arrayadapter-notifydatasetchanged-is-not-working)

Comment: Looked at the link, I presume the global variable needs to be built in a singleton class?

Comment: No, just on top of your activity. Something like this:

Comment: The suggested line is ArrayList<myList> myArrayList=new ArrayList<myList>();      and my current one is ArrayList<String>mylistarray = new ArrayList<>(); so I dont see the difference in my array and the one suggested?

Answer (score 0):

make sure of two things:

1 does `ADD_NEW_ITEM` equals `1`?

2 did you `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);` before you finish it(Create_Item_Activity)?

Comment: Yes for add new item it is: static final int ADD_NEW_ITEM = 1;

Comment: Yes in the intent in "create item activity" I have: setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnentry); within the

Comment: that's odd. Because your code above seems no error. It can work.

Comment: well, did you declare the `myadapter` out of the `onCreate` method?

Comment: when I remove the notifyDataSetChanged() from my onActivityResult the code does work, it happily passes the 2 x data fields from one activity to another and updates the array, and displays the values in the listview, I am not sure how it is refreshing the array without this line in, but it is doing it somehow?!

Comment: That's impossible. I cannot update the array without `notifyDataSetChanged`. There must be some mistakes.Mmmmmm......But anyway, you solve the problem. :D